# Azure Dev Ops: How to set a boolean item's default value on a work item template

Tags: azure-devops

I have all required permissions to do whatever I want. This is our bug item template. We have a pre-existing Boolean item we've used for years now (To be Triaged - pictured below). It used to be defaulting to false, I want to default to true.

Is the only way / correct way to do this via a custom rule on create? Seems odd. Other text based fields for example allow you to specify required (this is greyed out, presumably because it's a bool?) and subsequently a default. This does not. Seems to require an explicit "rule" be created.

[image]

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: @user2763557 Nope... created a custom rule instead.

Comment: what was your custom rule logic? having bit of trouble getting it to work through rules. It keeps defaulting to true even if i manually change it to false

Comment: @user2763557 I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find a way to do this without a custom rule. This rule worked for me:

[image]